# Is it safe to trust peerHost in HostnameVerifier?

Tags: java, security, ssl, sonarqube

In [one of the rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3510) SonarQube disallows a dummy `HostnameVerifier` that blindly accepts every host:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslcontext).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String requestedHost, SSLSession remoteServerSession) {
    return true;  // Noncompliant
  }
}).build();
```

and this example is provided as a compliant code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslcontext).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String requestedHost, SSLSession remoteServerSession) {
    return requestedHost.equalsIgnoreCase(remoteServerSession.getPeerHost()); // Compliant
  }
}).build();
```

However in javadoc for [SSLSession.getPeerHost()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerHost()) I can read that:

> This value is not authenticated and should not be relied upon. It is mainly used as a hint for SSLSession caching strategies.

This makes me confused. If the `getPeerHost()` value cannot be trusted then how it can be a recommended compliant code to fix the vulnerability? Is it safe or not? What kind of attacks it prevents and which it fails to prevent?

Comment: No. Terrible example. You're supposed to get the peer certificate from the session and compare the identity it asserts with the requested host.

Comment: @TMG, I have updated the code example for the rule, thanks for your feedback. Next time don't hesitate to share it on [the community forum](community.sonarsource.com/)

Answer (score 0):

While using the 'peerHost' rather than a blanket 'return true' is certainly much better, it's still not without risk.
The 'peerHost' [may be retrieved through reverse DNS](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/76783cd8cbb390dc9ac1da72962ce15e98ea5d3c/src/jdk.httpserver/share/classes/sun/net/httpserver/SSLStreams.java#L64). This results in a flaw of [CWE-350: Reliance on Reverse DNS Resolution for a Security-Critical Action](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/350.html) on which MITRE says the following:

> Since DNS names can be easily spoofed or misreported, and it may be difficult for the software to detect if a trusted DNS server has been compromised, DNS names do not constitute a valid authentication mechanism.
>
> When the software performs a reverse DNS resolution for an IP address, if an attacker controls the server for that IP address, then the attacker can cause the server to return an arbitrary hostname. As a result, the attacker may be able to bypass authentication, cause the wrong hostname to be recorded in log files to hide activities, or perform other attacks.
>
> Attackers can spoof DNS names by either (1) compromising a DNS server and modifying its records (sometimes called DNS cache poisoning), or (2) having legitimate control over a DNS server associated with their IP address.

The best course of action is to resolve the underlying issue of why the hostname given does not match the hostname in the certificate.
Note that SonarSource have updated their example code to reflect this: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5527